# Notification Service Extension Not working

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, ios10, serviceextension

Notification is not being displayed when I send `mutable-content:1` with push payload neither it hits the breakpoint inside the Notification service extension, although without mutable-content push is being displayed, also Notification content extension is working fine. I did not modify the code inside the Notification service extension it's the default generated by the Xcode. Am I missing something while creating a notification service extension or it might be the issue with the device setting? **I have tested on the same device a few days ago and the notification service extension was working fine.**

Below is my code for service extension

```
import UserNotifications

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            // Modify the notification content here...
            bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title) [modified]"
    
           contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }
}
```

edit 1: below is my push payload

```
{  
   "aps":{  
      "sound":"default",
      "mutable-content": 1,
      "category": "myCategory",
      "alert":{  
         "body":"this is a custom push",
         "subtitle":"subtitle of the push",
         "title":"Push Test"
      }
      
   }
}
```

edit1: The problem seems on that particular device running on 10.2.1, I checked with other device running on 10.2, it was triggering the Notification service extension.

Comment: How are you sending the Json containing "mutable-content:1" ? If it's with FCM change "-" by "_"

Comment: Hi @SeikoTheWiz i am not using FCM

Comment: Hi @princerk I am also trying to implement Notification Service Extension but it's not modifying my content even I am using the default apple code.
Do I need to enable Push Notification for the App Id I set for notification service extension?
Please help me with the steps required to make it work.

Comment: @Milan No need to enable the push notification for the service extension. Default code generated by xcode should do the work. make sure you are passing "mutable-content": 1 in your push payload. Try with other devices.

Comment: FWIW, you're not showing how you're modifying the payload.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve the issue. I am not sure what was causing the issue but after some experiments I realised that not only my service extension but all other installed app's service extension was not working and when sending the push payload with "mutable-content: 1, Notification was not displayed. After rebooting the device it started working fine. I was using iPhone 6s.

Comment: Recently some of my customer has same issue like this, and everything is working fine after rebooting. Do you find the root reason?

Answer (score 21):

**Deployment target of your NotificationServiceExtension can also be a reason.**

In my case, I was testing on Device running on iOS 12.4 while target
version of my NotificationServiceExtension was 14.1. I Just changed my
NotificationServiceExtension targeted version to 12.4 it Worked.

Comment: OMG That's exactly what caused the issue for me. 

Comment: WEEKS trying to figure out why it wasn't working on our QA flows, and this was the answer for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In my case I removed extension and add again. Then restart device..

[image]

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me 6/22/2022. After my app transfer, I had to remove this file and re-add it. Then the notification extension started working again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when I was debugging, the notification service extension was not getting launched by the system when it received a notification with the mutable content payload. I tried a lot and then figured out that in the run script, the `Copy only when installing` was checked. I unchecked it and I was able to debug the extensions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case it ended up being my extension using too much memory.
`Console.app` was only showing that Springboard was killing the app with an error like:

> CMSessionMgr- CMSessionMgrHandleApplicationStateChange: CMSession: Sending stop command to _ with pid '_' because client is not allowed to play in the background AND does not continue AirPlaying video when device locks

I thought something was wrong with the entitlements or something like that, but once I debugged it I saw that it was iOS killing the process for taking too much memory. Once I fixed that bug, the extension was kept alive until I called the callback.

Answer (score 0):

May not relate to the general issue if it exists, but I've spent a whole day trying to figure out why `AppMetrica` Push SDK campaign pushes won't come in `TestFlight` but come successfully when running from Xcode. For me it was "push environment" not being set to "production", but for "development":

in `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)` had to change it to:

```
let pushEnvironment = YMPYandexMetricaPushEnvironment.production
YMPYandexMetricaPush.setDeviceTokenFrom(deviceToken, pushEnvironment: pushEnvironment)
```